# Is it possible to debug a struct/class initialization member by member?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, vscode-debugger

Initializing a class like this:

```
var x = new Item()
{
 ID = (int)...,
 Name = (string)...,
 ..
};
```

I am getting an InvalidCastException on one of the assignments. There are quite a lot of them and the exception occurs on the whole expression even if I run the debugger line-by-line. The exception doesn't give any clue either what it's trying to cast to what.

Is there a way to debug each assignment individually? I've seen the debugger separately stops 3 times on expressions like `foreach(x in y)` so it seems a little strange it isn't doing that here, and detracts from the attraction of using this handy initialization syntax. Maybe there is a more fine-grained debug step I can use?

Comment: Do you have access to the source for `Item`? Can you put breakpoints on the setters for `ID`, `Name`?

Comment: @JeffE actually yeah I guess. I would at least be able to see the last one that gets called if I put breakpoints on evert setter. Not ideal but good thinking and better than commenting out code or trial and error :)

Comment: There is no way to do what you're asking (at least in the VS 2017 I use). Another idea is to use Ctrl-K/Ctrl-C to quickly comment-out blocks of object initializer code. If you do it in binary-search fashion, you can quickly home-in on the offending property.

Comment: If you want to narrow down a problematic assignment, why don't you try a line-by-line assignments for each of the properties or at least for some of them.
-------
var x = new Item();
x.ID = (int)...;
x.Name = (string)...;
...
-----
My apologies if I misunderstood your problem.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't get you... If you're talking about error handling, please refer this: [Exception Handling (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/exception-handling) and this: [Best practices for exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions)

Comment: If this question is about debugging, you've got few options when the program is in debug mode. `F10` - step over and `F11` - step into. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is "Is it possible to debug a struct/class initialization member by member?".

So, up front, I'm not directly answering *that* question as worded because when I carefully read the body of your post it sounds like the essential question is how to identify the 'smoking line' root cause of this InvalidCastException right when it happens.

What I've found in similar situations is that if Visual Studio can be made to break at the moment the InvalidCastException occurs i.e. *on that specific line* then the Call Stack and local variables are much more immediate and useful.

Unfortunately, 'break when thrown' is suppressed by Visual Studio default settings for many exception types. But it's very easy to turn on 'break when thrown' for ALL exceptions. Just change this default setting in the Exceptions window in Visual Studio from this:

[image: Default Exception Settings]

to this:

[image]

This doesn't "always" help but it's a good start. It's so easy why not try that first to see if rapid resolution is possible. Hope this turns out to be useful in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is an option in VS 2017, I only have 2019 at hand. In your settings under *Options -> Debugging -> General*, uncheck *Step over properties and operators*. Then set a break point at your initializer and step through it with F11 (Step-Into). You will hit each property setter until the exception is thrown.

Comment: That's an awfully good point and yes I can tell you for sure that this setting has been available as long as I can remember (back to, say, VS 2005). Yeah, without that the whole 'debugging properties' thing is a non-starter.

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse me if I am missing something (will delete if thats the case) but using an invalid cast like this:

```cs
struct Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Derived Derived { get; set; }
}
public class Base
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Derived : Base
{
    public string AdditionalProperty { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
var baseClass = new Base()
{
    Name = "foo",
};
try
{
    var x = new Item()
    {
          ID = (int)20,
          Derived = (Derived)baseClass,
    };
}
catch(Exception e)
{
          Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

neatly catches the error like this
`Unable to cast object of type 'Base' to type 'Derived'.`
in vs2017

However this breaks on the first error, we might wanna initalize an object this way and log all cast errors withouth exiting the initialisation. We can do this by implementing our own casting for this sample:

```cs
public static T TryCast<T>(Object _object)
        {
            try
            {
                return (T)_object;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Cant cast object of type {_object.GetType().ToString()} to object of type {typeof(T)}");
            }
            return default(T);
        }
 public static T TryCast<T>(IConvertible _object)
        {
            try
            {
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(_object, typeof(T));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Cant convert object of type {_object.ToString()} to object of type {typeof(T)}");
            }
            return default(T);
        }
```

New types for demonstrating purposes

```cs
struct Item
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public double FooDouble { get; set; }
        public Base Base { get; set; }
        public Derived Derived { get; set; }
        public string Bar { get; set; }
    }
    public class Base
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class Derived : Base
    {
        public string AdditionalProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

We can then initalize our object like this:

```cs
var derived = new Derived()
            {
                Name = "DerivedFoo",
                AdditionalProperty = "Bar"
            };
            var _base = new Base()
            {
                Name = "BaseFoo"
            };
            var x = new Item()
            {
                ID = Utils.TryCast<int>("please no"),
                FooDouble = Utils.TryCast<double>(2),
                Base = Utils.TryCast<Base>(derived),
                Derived = Utils.TryCast<Derived>(_base),
                Bar = "Foo"
            };
```

And we neatly log any errors that might occur when casting:

[image: Result in the console]

Comment: The Problem with your solution is that all too often, it will not help at all because it ignores conversions, e.g. (T) with T=int is much different to (int). The former will only work if the passed object really is an int while the latter will also work for an uint.

Comment: You are correct, would implementing another overload for TryCast solve this issue ? see edit

Comment: Yes, I think the overload will solve this Problem at least if the Compiler knows what the actual type is. Then, the only remaining Problem is that the solution via IConvertible comes with Boxing, which causes a bit of overhead. Whether this Overhead is acceptable probably depends on the Scenario.